# How to add devices into Sun J2ME Emulator?

Tags: java, configuration, java-me, emulation, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

using Mac OSX, how can I add a device into J2ME Emulator?

I have J2ME SDK 3.0 installed twice (standalone and as a part of Netbeans 7 bundle)

emulator is in path:

```
/Applications/Java_ME_SDK_3.0.app/Contents/Resources/runtimes/cldc-hi-javafx/bin/runMidlet
```

list of available devices configurations:

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 user  admin  272 16 pro  2009 ClamshellCldcPhone  
drwxr-xr-x   5 muser  admin  170 16 pro  2009 DefaultCldcJtwiPhone  
drwxr-xr-x   8 userd  admin  272 16 pro  2009 DefaultCldcPhone  
drwxr-xr-x  10 user  admin  340 16 pro  2009 DefaultFxPhone  
drwxr-xr-x  10 user  admin  340 16 pro  2009 DefaultFxTouchPhone  
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  admin  102 16 pro  2009 ExternalDevice
```

in folder `/Applications/Java_ME_SDK_3.0.app/Contents/Resources/toolkit-lib/devices`

I need for example J2ME MIDP2.0 CLDC1.1 360x640 device (touch screen, such as [C5-03](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/C5-03/) or so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You can't add the that type of devices with Java ME SDK 3.0 on Mac OS X. If you want to test real time means you can go with [Nokia RDA devices.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/) Also see this article, [Emulator to run on Mac os x.](http://www.techgainer.com/3-tools-to-run-cell-phone-java-jar-softwares-games-on-windows-linux-macpc/)

Comment: Solved by using MPowerPlayer SDK (mpp-sdk) with great emulator running inside. Thanks